# Rationality of a representation on the space of regular functions

Tags: representation-theory

It seems that the question is about the Chevalley's classification of rational representations, but I could not locate the reference, and also not figure out a proof.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and $G:={\rm GL}_n(k).$ We say a representation (i.e. a group homomorphism) $\rho\colon G\to {\rm GL}(V)$ for some finite-dimensional $k$-vector space $V$ is rational if given a basis under which ${\rm GL}(V)\simeq {\rm GL}_N(k),$ $\rho(g)_{ab}$ is a polynomial in the entries of $g$ and $\det g^{-1}$ for any $1\le a,b\le N.$

Let $Reg(G)$ be the set of regular functions of $G,$ i.e., functions $f\colon G\to k$ which is a polynomial in the entries of $g$ and $\det g^{-1}.$ Then any rational representation $\rho$ induces a representation $\rho^* $on $Reg(G)$ by
$$\rho^*(g)\colon h\mapsto f(g^{-1}h).$$

Now let $W$ be a finite-dimentional $k$-subspace of $Reg(G),$ which is invariant under the $G$-action. Thus there is a well-defined representation
$$\varphi\colon G\to{\rm GL}(W).$$
${\bf My ~Question:}$ It turns out that $\varphi$ is also a rational representation, but I am not sure how to prove it. Specifying a basis doesn't help me to do so.

I also try to do a special case when $W={\rm span}\{gf_0\mid g\in G\}$ for a given specified $f_o\in Reg(G)$ (which could be checked to be finite-dimensional), but I still don't know how to show that this is rational.

Any comment is welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say a polynomial in the entries of $g$ and $\det g$, do you mean a polynomial in the entries of $g$ and $(\det g)^{-1}$? This is my understanding of what a regular function on $G$ is (and the determinant itself is a polynomial in the entries of $g$ anyway).

Comment: @Joppy Exactly. I have edited them. It turns out that I have figured it out.